# jQuery multiple .not() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to exclude two elements using `.not()` method but it doesn't seem to work:

```
this.btn            = $('button.submit', this.$element);
this.cancel         = $("input[name='cancel']", this.$element);
this.formInputs     = $(':input', this.form).not(this.cancel, this.btn);
```

jQuery does select the `this.btn` and `this.cancel` alright, just doesn't exclude it inside `.not`

This works though:

```
$(':input', this.form).not(this.cancel).not(this.btn);
```

Comment: Create a fiddle for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the elements into an array.

```
$(':input', this.form).not([this.cancel, this.btn]);
```

Or

```
$(':input', this.form).not([this.cancel[0], this.btn[0]]);
```

Should work